# .js File being deleted automatically windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, filesystems, javascript

When I run a javascript file, or just leave it, it is being deleted automatically by windows. I've tried on many different code editors and given the code editors admin, but it is still the same result. I have even tried to disable my antivirus, but it still deletes the file automatically, even if I rename it.

The file contains the same code, and it is a javascript file every time

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: What is in the .js file?

Comment: A discord bot main file

Comment: Is it any js file, or just ones containing this code? Use a utility like Process Monitor to see which process is deleting the file.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the answers to the questions you are being asked.

Comment: It is just containing this code